# Remove not working inside script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Created the below script to keep only the latest 3 files, but the rm command is not deleting the files.

```
#!/bin/sh
count=$(ls -1 /var/mds_backup/archives | wc -l)
echo "$count"
if [ "$count" -gt "3" ]; then
    difference=`expr $count - 3`
    rm -f $(ls -1t  /var/mds_backup/archives | tail -n $difference)
else
    echo "Nothing to Delete !!!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `ls -1t  /var/mds_backup/archives` will show file names in directory without path, the path is missing, this is why rm can't delete file.
  Parsing ls is not safe. however to sort files by last access time can't be done with bash builtins because to get last time modification an external command must be called. I would use a perl command instead.

a quick fix is to replace `ls -1t /var/mds_backup/archives` by `ls -1td /var/mds_backup/archives/*` , `-d` to avoid listing directories if exist. before to execute `rm` command can be prefixed by `echo` to avoid removing unwanted files.

EDIT: to correct my answer it can be done with builtins implementing a quick sort in bash using `[[ $filea -nt $fileb ]]` test.

for example

```
files=( /var/mds_backup/archives/* )

qs() {
  local l=() g=() p=$1
  r=();shift||return
  for i; do [[ $i -nt $p ]] && l+=("$i") || g+=("$i"); done
  qs "${l[@]}"; l=("${r[@]}")
  qs "${g[@]}"; g=("${r[@]}")
  r=("${l[@]}" $p "${g[@]}")
}

qs "${files[@]}"

echo "${r[@]:3}"
rm  "${r[@]:3}"
```